# Equal Partitioning with Minimum Sum Difference

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to write this algorithm in Java following the steps below:(I know other solutions, just trying to figure out this one)

```
int min_diff = LARGE_NUMBER;
int diff;
for (each subset S of size n/2 of A) {
    diff = abs(sum(S) – sum(A-S));
    if (diff < min_diff) {
        min_diff = diff;
        TempSet = S;
     }

 }
print min_diff, TempSet;
```

I tried to find all subset permutations of size n/2 using the code from this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-subsets-given-size-set/
The code in this link print all permutations. I thought first I need to store the arrays in an ArrayList so I can use them in the for loop, but I couldn't get it to work. The code below gives wrong output (every array is 60 60 60 instead of permutations:

```
static List<int[]> intArrays = new ArrayList<>();

static void combinationUtil(int[]arr, int n, int r, int index, int[] data, int i)
{

    if (index == r) {           
        intArrays.add(data);
        return;           
    }

    if (i >= n)
        return;

    data[index] = arr[i];
    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index + 1, data, i + 1);
    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index, data, i + 1);


}

static void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r)
{

    int data[] = new int[r];
    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, 0, data, 0);
    for(int[] arr1:intArrays){
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int arr[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40,50,60};
    int n=arr.length;
    int r=n/2;

    printCombination(arr, n, r);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? Or how can I solve this problem following the above steps?

Comment: You can solve this task more effecively (if data range is reasonable) using dynamic programming approach - look for `subset sum problem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is when you do `intArrays.add(data);`

`intArrays` always contains the reference to `data` array. The array is passed by reference. You gets {60, 60, 60} because is the last state of `data` array (the last subset).

To fix the problem you must to do `intArrays.add(data.Clone());` if exists `Clone` function or similar in you language or just implement it yourself.

Code in C#. Sorry I don't have any java compiler installed.

```
static int[] CloneArray(int[] arr)
{
    int[] ret = new int[arr.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i) ret[i] = arr[i];
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This did fix my problem! :)